# Preventing a single word at the end of a line in a paragraph using CSS only

Tags: css

I've looked all around the internet and the css specifications/proposals, and I'm not even sure I'm looking for the right thing here... CSS Widows and Orphans seem to only apply to column'd text.

Is there a way to prevent a single word from being on it's own line at the end of a paragraph? For example:

```
This is my paragraph and I don't want a 
single word to be hanging at the end like 
this.
```

Rather I would want:

```
This is my paragraph and I want at least 
two words to be hanging at the end 
like this.
```

I'm trying to not insert any nbsps, or add any additional tags because this content is being dynamically generated. Hoping to find a pure CSS solution!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe try with text-align:justify . Also post what you have tried (html +css)

Comment: CSS widow and orphans work only on media print and affecting last lines of a page...

Comment: The code is only text inside a paragraph tag. For example, <p>Text inside this paragraph tag</p>. I'm hoping to achieve this _without_ adding any additional html or content inside the paragraph tag. I'm also hoping to achieve this without javascript. so- only a style inside p { ... }. 

That being said, there may not be an answer to this problem :)

Comment: I think there isn't a solution to what you're asking for. Because you're looking for a dynamic programmatic solution that I assume runs against dynamic text. You would have to use some kind of scripting to parse the text. BUT if it's actually static, you can do as others have suggested and wrap some elements in extra span/div's